# Makefile to add shell aliases

Tags: bash, makefile, sh

I am already using a makefile, and I was hoping to be able to use it to store a few useful aliases that the user could then invoke. I know that I can make a bash file with the aliases already built in, so and run it with source, so I can do something like:

```
# File: aliases.sh
alias useful="command to run"
alias also-useful="another command -to run"
```

Then I can run this in the current terminal session with:

```
source ./aliases.sh
```

## Using a Makefile

So I was hoping to achieve something similar with a makefile, I was hoping to have a simple `aliases` entry, so the user could just run:

```
make aliases
```

I prefer to avoid adding an extra file if this is at all possible, because I don't want to add extra files for such simple tasks. If you have any suggestions that would be better, I'd be open to hearing them too.

Comment: What's wrong with `source ./aliases.sh`?

Comment: I wanted this to happen as part of my build process. So if the user calls `make development`, it will run various tasks that are required to start developing. It would be nice to add these aliases as a pre-step into their development environment. I also just don't want file clutter because I have a few use cases like this, so having one file to handle this would be preferable.

Comment: You want `aliases` not `recipes` right? Generally `aliases` are handled either through the system-wide shell settings or on a per-user basis through the user profile or run-control file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`). This is necessary as they effect the shell environment and whether through a subsequent script or makefile, neither can effect the environment of the parent (e.g. the user's shell). The only way to set additional aliases after login is to `source` at the command line, otherwise the aliases will only be present in a particular subshell. So it is somewhat unclear what you are wanting.

Comment: Yes I did want to add commands to the parent shell, which MadScientist pointed out is impossible without running source. I think I will just have to write a shell script to do this for me.

Comment: You want a shell *function* to create shell *functions*, not a shell *script* to create *aliases.* Learn to embrace functions and avoid aliases; the latter are very limited and less versatile.

Comment: awesome, I'll look into them :) Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you're asking is for `make aliases` to create aliases that you can then invoke at your shell prompt, something like:

```
$ make aliases
$ useful
```

then that is impossible and the reason has nothing to do with `make`.

In a UNIX/POSIX system the process hierarchy is strict: a process starts one or more sub-processes, and each of those can start more, etc.  So a login manager process starts your shell (or your window manager), your shell starts `make`, which is another process, and `make` will run another shell as a subprocess to run each recipe, and each shell will run programs like compilers, commands like `rm` which are also processes, etc.

It is a fundamental rule of all processes that they cannot modify the environment (memory) of their parents (and they can only modify the environment of their children before they are started).  So, if you start a new shell and change your working directory then exit that shell, the parent's shell is not changed.  If you set an environment variable in the child process, the variable is not set in the parent.  Etc.

Shell aliases are part of a particular shell's memory.  So a program you start cannot create aliases in its parent shell.  It doesn't matter if that program is `make` or anything else.

That's why you have to use the special command `source` to load those into your shell: instead of running a new shell, the `source` command tells the current shell to run the commands in the script as if you'd typed them in at the command line... so no new process is created and the current shell's environment and memory is modified.  If you ran your `aliases` file as a shell script, via `aliases` rather than `source aliases`, then a new shell would be created, the aliases would be defined, then the shell would exit and all the aliases would be gone again.

So, all that to say it's not possible for `make` to define aliases in the shell that invokes it: the operating system won't allow it.

Comment: Awesome awesome, thanks for that! So you'd suggest that source is the only way to go here right? I feared as much, but this answer really clarified things for me. Thanks again :)

Comment: You can use `source` (or it's more portable counterpart `.`, as in `. aliases`), or you can modify your shell's configuration file (`~/.bashrc` or similar... details depends on which shell you use) to set up the aliases but then of course they'll always be defined in all shells.  Or you can write a shell function which sources the alias file, like `mkaliases() { source aliases; }`.  Those are your only choices essentially.