# Makefile unable to run source command

Tags: python, makefile

I'm trying to create a makefile for my machine learning project in python. Below is a sample code of it.

```
.PHONY: setup_env remove_env data features train predict run clean test
PROJECT_NAME=my-project

ifeq (,$(shell which pyenv))
    HAS_PYENV=False
    CONDA_ROOT=$(shell conda info --root)
    BINARIES = ${CONDA_ROOT}/envs/${PROJECT_NAME}/bin
else
    HAS_PYENV=True
    CONDA_VERSION=$(shell echo $(shell pyenv version | awk '{print $$1;}') | awk -F "/" '{print $$1}')
    BINARIES = $(HOME)/.pyenv/versions/${CONDA_VERSION}/envs/${PROJECT_NAME}/bin
endif

setup_env:
ifeq (True,$(HAS_PYENV))
    @echo ">>> Detected pyenv, setting pyenv version to ${CONDA_VERSION}"
    pyenv local ${CONDA_VERSION}
    conda env create --name $(PROJECT_NAME) -f environment.yaml --force
    pyenv local ${CONDA_VERSION}/envs/${PROJECT_NAME}
else
#   @echo ">>> Creating conda environment."
#   conda env create --name $(PROJECT_NAME) -f environment.yaml --force
    @echo ">>> Activating new conda environment"
    source $(CONDA_ROOT)/bin/activate $(PROJECT_NAME)
endif
```

The idea here is to create a conda environment from the yaml file and activate it. However, when I run this file in my terminal I'm getting the following error.

```
source /Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate my-project
make: source: No such file or directory
make: *** [setup_env] Error 1
```

Could you please help me fix this?

Comment: Does the file `/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate` exist?

Comment: Yes it does. For example instead of using the makefile if I run the following command directly in the terminal, it works

`source /Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate my-project`

Comment: It will not work in any way you want. `source` is the shell command that includes contents of a script into current shell session. `make` runs each line in a separate shell invocation. Whatever you `source` in one line, will not affect other lines, let alone different targets. If you need to set up environment, you should do so before running `make`.

Comment: Andreas tells you why you are getting the error you're getting: you can't use bash constructs by default in a makefile.  But even if you fix this it won't work, as hinted at by raspy.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50939834/939557

Answer (score 2):

`source` is `bash` only. GNU Make runs `sh` (by default), not `bash`. The `sh` equivalent to `bash` `source` is `.`.

Change the offending line to this:

```
. $(CONDA_ROOT)/bin/activate $(PROJECT_NAME)
```

Comment: Tried this and its not working. This command is just printing the following into the terminal `. /Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate my-project`

Comment: Perhaps `activate` is bash-only. In that case you'd have to do `bash /Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate my-project`. Or just `/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate my-project` and let the shebang do its thing.